# Eliminate input text except alphabetical in python

Tags: python, string

Make a `caseSophia` function with a txt argument (string type), this function will:

- Exchange lowercase to uppercase
- Exchange uppercase to lowercase
- for other character except alphabetical will be erased from this `caseSophia` function.
- Type of this output is `string`.

This is my code:

```
def caseShopia(txt):
    pass
```

Run/Invoke function:

```
print(caseShopia('thXGth876%^$LMn.'))
```

Expected output:

```
THxgTHlmN
```

Comment: It seems that you are looking for someone to make instead of  you the homework. Anyway, if you want to find a solution, have a look on string.lower() and string.upper()

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
def caseShopia(txt):
    return ''.join(c.swapcase() for c in txt if c.isalpha())
```

Explanation:

1. It is using a python comprehension

```
c.swapcase() for c in txt if c.isalpha()
```

2. You filter just alpha characters

```py
if c.isalpha()
```

3. You convert to lower-case if the character is upper-case and viceversa

```py
c.swapcase()
```

4. One you have process that string, you join it together into a new string.

```py
''.join(...)
```

I hope this helps you. Since you are new to Python you might have trouble understanding the comprehension, so this code uses a for loop:

```py
def caseShopia(txt):
    s = ''
    for c in txt:
        if c.isalpha():
            s += c.swapcase()
    return s
```

Comment: `c.swapcase()` would be perfect for this

Comment: @ScootCork, thank you so much for that hint. I was not aware of that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use islower() and isupper() methods to check if the character is lowercase or uppercase respectively and then convert lowercase character to uppercase character and vice-versa using upper() and lower().
Example code:-

```
def caseShopia(txt):
    output = []
    for letter in txt:
        if letter.islower():
            output.append(letter.upper())
        elif letter.isupper():
            output.append(letter.lower())
    return ''.join(output)
```

Here we create a list and then join the list to form a string and return the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your string and check to see if the character is alphabet or not using char.isalpha() function. Then in the inner if, check if the character is uppercase then convert it to the lower and visa versa, using char.lower() and char.upper() functions.

```
def caseShopia(x):
    s = ''
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i].isalpha():
            if (x[i].isupper()) == True:
                s += x[i].lower()
            else:
                s += x[i].upper()
    return s

print(caseShopia('thXGth876%^$LMn.'))
```